# Error in Power Automate Approval Flow with dyanmic approvers in SharePoint List

Tags: power-automate

I am in the process of building a PowerAutomate approval process, grabbing approvers from a SharePoint List. I am then updating the item's status on an Approval Dashboard.

Here are the images of my flow:

[image: Step 1] - the Select operation is using first(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])['Approvers']

[image: Step2]

[image: Step3] - the join statement is join(body('Select'), ';')

And here is the list item I'm trying to grab-- it is only one person currently for demo purposes, will be multiple when it's working:

[image: SharePoint List Item]

This is the error I'm getting when it hits the first "Start and Wait for Approval" step (I have X'd out the name, but it is the correct name from the list):

> The request failed. Error code: 'GraphLookUpRequestFailedError'. Error Message: 'User lookup request to Graph failed lookup for user identifier: '[[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|XXXXX@XXXXX","DisplayName":"XXXXXX","Email":"XXXXXXXX","Picture":'.'.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead in the Select From field?

```
first(items('Apply_to_each')['Approvers'])
```

And try this in the Map field

```
item()['Email']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't seem to take it, throwing error:
'InvalidTemplate' and message 'The template validation failed: 'The inputs of template action 'Select' at line '1 and column '2026' is invalid. Action 'Apply_to_each' must be a parent 'foreach' scope of action 'Select' to be referenced by 'repeatItems' or 'items' functions.'.'.